# #REF error when using INDEX function

Tags: excel, indexing

I cannot understand why everytime I use INDEX in excel to find a value given the two criteria, I get a #REF error.

```
INDEX(C2:L1048576,MATCH(O1,A2:A1048576,0),MATCH(O2,B2:B1048576,0))
```

There were no deleted cells, nor were they shifted at any point in time. They have the same number of rows too. The arrays to search into are correct.

Thanks. I would appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance. I am new to the INDEX formula.

Comment: what does "evaluate formula" show you? do both `MATCH` output a valid number? Also `INDEX([Matrix],[Row],[Column])` so `MATCH(O1,A2:A1048576,0)` tells the row to pick and `MATCH(O2,B2:B1048576,0)` shows the column... going from C to L the second part can only be 1-10

Comment: your second criteria is returning in the position of what column to look in, and your selected range only goes to L which is a far cry from column number 1048576

Answer (score 1):

The formula you're using doesn't find a value according to two criteria. The comments you were given explain what you're actually doing.

1. INDEX returns **one** cell value from a given range, according to a row and column index - the location within your range, starting with 1. (If your reference has only one row or column, one of them can be omitted).
2. MATCH finds a value in a range and returns its index.

So finding one value in a one-dimension range is easy using these two functions, using something like this (with a range of one column and multiple rows) `=INDEX(range,MATCH(value,range,0),1)`.

To find two criteria you need to tweak this concept. One way is to use **concatenation** of strings, using the `&` operator, and for this you'll also need to use an **array formula** (entering it using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>) like this formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$1048576,MATCH(O1&O2,$A$2:$A$1048576&$B$2:$B$1048576,0),1)
```

It's not clear what you are trying to return, so this formula will return the corresponding value in column `C`. You can use this concept to return each value from the rest of the columns `D:L`, one by one, or concatenate them.